# Quick way to host a webserver on localhost

Tags: command-line, webserver

I'd like to make the contents of a folder available at `http://localhost:PORT/`, temporarily. A very basic http server.

I already know about,

```
 $ python -m SimpleHttpServer
```

or ( this seems like the new way )

```
 $ python -m http.server
```

but I'm looking for alternate command-line methods.

Comment: @Stefan Are you looking for a way to temporarily host a given directory, or just looking for how to start webservers? (Your title and description don't seem to line up)

Comment: @Stefan and what's in this folder? are you just looking to run something for development? production? if production did you have a certain server in mind (e.g. apache, nginx)

Comment: Really wanted this to be **community wiki**, but it seems I dont have that option. Anyway, I clarified the question.

Comment: @Stefan You can flag for mod attention if you think a post should be CW, but I'm not sure this actually should be. I'm not the best authority on the proper usage of CW though

Comment: The question I had in mind was to be CW, but this has morphed into something else...

Comment: Why would the first example you gave(python -m SimpleHttpServer) not work?

Comment: @Stefan I'm still a little confused... is this about starting a python webserver on the command line?

Comment: @Kevin take a look at [2.5.2 docs](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/module-SimpleHTTPServer.html) and the  [3.1 docs](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1/library/http.server.html). I ran `SimpleHttpServer` and got a "module is not installed error", and running the arg "http.server" worked.

Comment: @xeno in essence yes, just quick ways ( always in the command-line as opposed to a gui ) of running a very basic webserver ( no need for php or anything like that ). The second python command solved my problem, but i'd like to know if there are any other ways, and how to use them... ( By using ruby's webrick server for example )

Comment: @stefan I can name 10 webservers off the top of my head, and the 6 java, 3 c, 1 perl and proper way to start them depends on what your goal is (daemon? or running where ctrl-c can kill it), and your distro( apache2 on gentoo, httpd on centos). given I only know 10, and I'm sure there are 10x plus 10x ways to run them... that's too many options, that's why I feel "This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form." but since no one else is voting to close i'm leaving it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing like a "system' webserver in unix and different "methods".

You can install software on your system which contains a simple webserver and use it or not.

`python -m SimpleHttpServer` just loads the SimpleHttpServer module, which contains a basic webserver.

Something simliar exists for Perl, just have a look at CPAN: http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTTP-Server-Simple/

"Simple" is a solution for Java: http://www.simpleframework.org/

The same can be really easy achived with JavaScript and nodejs: http://nodejs.org/api.html , see the section about HTTP.

Another solution would be to do it yourself: HTTP is a really simple protocol, when it comes to only serve some static files. To get /foo/bar your browser will request it with:

```
GET /foo/bar HTTP/1.1
```

The reply should be in the following form:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Last-Modified: Tue, 10 Jan 2010 11:11:11 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

YOUR CONTENT
```

or

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Last-Modified: Tue, 10 Jan 2010 11:11:11 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

YOUR 404 ERROR PAGE
```

Include the Last-Modified header to enable caching of the ressources.
It should be possible to write a minimal implementation of this in a few lines of code. Tie it to a port and you will have your webserver up and running. Use inetd or netcat to bind it to your IP.

Edit: Here is a simple shellscript which does exactly this job. It also supports generating an index for the folders and 404 error handling:

- SWS Manpage:
  http://prd4.wynn.com:8080/src/sws.8.html
- SWS Source:
  http://prd4.wynn.com:8080/src/sws.txt
- SWS Project Page:
  http://prd4.wynn.com:8080/README.html